# I need help demonstrating proof of funds for multiple jobs

Tags: visas, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

I have 2 jobs. My father has a company in which he does manufacturing, import and export. I run this job part time (for now) as the Manager in my father's absence. I also work as a consultant for a Bank as an engineer. This is the job I have full time, and I have the salary paid into my account. (I also have the payslips)

Now I want to apply to Canada for a visit/tourist visa to visit family, I am Nigerian.  I have gotten documents for the company which my father runs (including bank statements).

Now here is what worries me, since I work as a consultant for a bank and my bank statement bears my salaries and I have payslips as proof, and I also have Bank statements, Company registration documents and sworn affidavit, can I also add that as well to this documentation judging that I have enough proof of funds to sponsor me in Canada and ties back home?

Comment: You should provide documentation that substantiates the source of all regular credits to your account (such as your salary) and any material unusual receipts.

Answer (score 5):

Many people have multiple jobs so this is not an unusual situation, and the visa officers will understand that.

Explain in your letter the nature of the two jobs as you have done here. When you submit all the proof be sure to make it clear what job each one applies to. Submit proof of payment for both jobs as you have mentioned, such as the payslips and your bank statement.

Ensure that all the incoming money into your bank account is explained, so it doesn't look like you are simply parking funds in the account to help with your application.

Explaining the nature of both of these jobs will also help to prove proof of ties to your home country, ensuring that you will leave at the end of your trip. Get a letter from both companies stating that you will be allowed a set time off to take this trip, and that you will then be expected back to continue your work. You can also include many other types of proof of ties, but I won't list them here as this question is about the funds.